# Boost C++ : compilation error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, boost, compilation

I'm working with the Boost C++ library since a long time and suddenly I got stranges error when I compile my software with Visual Studio 2012 (in debug 64 bits). I have absolutely no idea of the problem and the "output" does not really help me.

Here are the kind of errors I got (the output):

```
_libraries\lib_Boost\boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp(847): error C2059: syntax error : ','
```

And the following one too :

```
_libraries\lib_Boost\boost/filesystem/operations.hpp(798): error C2678: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'boost::filesystem::directory_iterator' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
          _libraries\lib_Boost\boost/filesystem/path.hpp(621): could be 'bool boost::filesystem::operator !=(const boost::filesystem::path &,const boost::filesystem::path &)'
          _libraries\lib_Boost\boost/filesystem/path.hpp(622): or       'bool boost::filesystem::operator !=(const boost::filesystem::path &,const boost::filesystem::path::string_type &)'
          _libraries\lib_Boost\boost/filesystem/path.hpp(623): or       'bool boost::filesystem::operator !=(const boost::filesystem::path::string_type &,const boost::filesystem::path &)'
          _libraries\lib_Boost\boost/filesystem/path.hpp(624): or       'bool boost::filesystem::operator !=(const boost::filesystem::path &,const boost::filesystem::path::value_type *)'
          _libraries\lib_Boost\boost/filesystem/path.hpp(625): or       'bool boost::filesystem::operator !=(const boost::filesystem::path::value_type *,const boost::filesystem::path &)'
          while trying to match the argument list '(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator, boost::filesystem::directory_iterator)'
```

Does someone has an idea that can help me to find the reason of theses errors ?
Is there some compilation options that can help ?

I only have theses 2 errors (a lot of time !!)

Thanks

Comment: Is it a compiler error or a linker error ? I had once this kind of linker error, it was a mismatch between my sources and my binaries (sources was updated by libraries not)

Comment: It is a compilation error, C2678 is a compilation error ! Thx

Comment: Hi,

The problem is fixed.

It seems to me that it is the VS2012 compiler that drives crazy !

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Did you find out what was wrong? Please answer your own question if you do so. It might help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the issue, it is related to a bug in Visual Studio 2012 C++ compiler.

In a completely unrelated file I have some code like this :

```
#ifdef SUPPORT_THIS_FEATURE

... some code ....

#endif
```

I have just remove this code and all works fine !

Of course, SUPPORT_THIS_FEATURE was NOT defined !